# React Native Deep Linking not redirecting to specified Screen

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement deep linking in React Native folowing this doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links.

The main problem here is that i'm not able to open a specific screen, it always open the main screen.

I'm currently only testing in iOS, but in Android same occurs.

I defined custom url scheme

```xml
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
   <string>com.react_native_starter_kit</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
   <string>test</string>
   </array>
</dict>
```

Defined linking obj

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['test://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      App: {
        screens: {
          Settings: 'settings/:id',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And Navigation

```js
export const Router = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <Main />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const Main = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      initialRouteName={routesName.App}>
      {userToken ? (
        <Stack.Screen name={routesName.App} component={TabNavigator} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Auth} component={AuthStack} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const TabNavigator = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={routesName.Home}
        component={HomeStack}
        options={navigationOptions(routesName.Home, theme)}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={routesName.Settings}
        component={SettingsStack}
        options={navigationOptions(routesName.Settings, theme)}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

When i type `test://settings/123`, inside safari, or `xcrun simctl openurl booted test://settings/123` it should open settings tab, but it always only open main screen. I've tryied a lot of `linkin` obj combinations, same result always. Even when i remove `linking={linking}` the behavior is the same, app opens main screen. It is like navigation is ignoring `linking={linking}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your linking object should be like this

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['test://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      App: {
        path: "app",
        screens: {
          Settings: 'settings/:id',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And after saving this run this command to test the deep link

> npx uri-scheme open test://app/settings/778GHFHG --ios

Comment: This doesn't work for me? Any other ideas? Any ideas how to debug why it doesn't redirect?

Comment: for me at least the links are case sensitive *FIXED*

Comment: for some reason deep links don't work if you have debug on. try again with debug off